# determine whether sum converges or diverges: $\sum ^\infty_{n=2} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi n^2}{n+1})}{\log^2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

determine whether sum converges or diverges: $\sum ^\infty_{n=2} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi n^2}{n+1})}{\log^2n}$

tried to use regular convergence tests, no success so far.

Comment: Well, for large $n$ the numerator alternates signs, and the absolute value of the terms decrease to $0$ so...

Comment: well you know this isn't enough.

Comment: Why is it not enough?

Comment: counter example 1/n->0 and its sum diverge.

Comment: That is not an alternating series.  The alternating bit is crucial.  $\sum \frac {(-1)^n}n$ converges, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rigorous proof could be the following:

1. $$
   \begin{gathered}
     \cos \left( {\frac{{\pi n^2 }}
   {{n + 1}}} \right) = \cos \left[ {\pi \left( {n - 1} \right) + \frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right] =  \hfill \\
      \hfill \\
      = \cos \left[ {\pi \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right]\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right) - \sin \left[ {\pi \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right]\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
      \hfill \\
      = \left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} \cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right) \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered} 
   $$
2. $$
   \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos \left( {\frac{{\pi n^2 }}
   {{n + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{\log ^2 n}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} \frac{{\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{\log ^2 n}}} 
   $$
3. We prove now that 
   $$
   a_n  = \frac{{\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{n + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{\log ^2 n}} \downarrow 0\,\,\,\,\,\,n \to  + \infty 
   $$
4. Let be
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{{\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{x + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{\log ^2 x}}
   $$
   with $x \geq 2$. Then
   $$
   f'(x) =  - \frac{{2\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{x + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{x\log ^3 (x)}} + \frac{{\pi \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{x + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{(x + 1)^2 \log ^2 (x)}}
   $$
   thus
   $$
   f'(x) =  - \frac{{2\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }
   {{x + 1}}} \right)}}
   {{x\log ^3 (x)}} + o\left( {\frac{1}
   {{x\log ^3 (x)}}} \right)
   $$
   as $x \to +\infty$. This means that eventually $f'(x)<0$ and therefore $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing as well as $a_n$. Now the series is convergent by Leibniz Test.

Answer (score 0):

well it's as simple as using a theorem.
This is an alternating series which monotonically converges to 0.
So according to Leibniz it converges. 
thanks to @lulu

Comment: You still need to *prove* it's alternating. Not a very hard task, but that requires a proof.